# Safest way to copy files from Windowsserver to Azure storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, windows-server

We are migrating a files from on-prem to cloud. My task is to copy huge files from server(Windowserver) to Azure storage. What is the safest way to copy those files from Windows server to Azure storage?
Are there any tools I should use? I don't know if I should download tools on a windowserver...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Microsoft provided `AzCopy` tool,  you can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). It has several optimization [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize) so that you can make concurrent file uploads making full use of your hardware capabilities.